# Transitive Verbs without Passive Structures (voice)

Tags: verbs

> I got a letter yesterday.

*Get* is a transitive verb. But if we want to transform the sentence into  passive?

> The letter was...received yesterday. 
>   *Get* has no passive voice  (LDOCE).Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English 
>   Get 1.receive, **[T not in passive ]**,to be given or receive something.

Though there is a past participle (got,gotten),it doesn't necessarily mean that we can form passive voice (according to the dictionary ).

Are there other transitive verbs, which don't have passive voice? Is there a special term for them (to read more)?

Comment: Thirty-seven parking tickets were gotten by the scofflaw in a period of only sixty days.  (AmE)

Comment: Thanks, then it might be British, right?

Answer (score 3):

In order to use the passive voice, we need the past participle of *get*.
According to Wiktionary, [get](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/get#Verb) has two past participles

> 1. got  (chiefly British)
> 2. gotten (North America, archaic in UK)

Further, Merriam-Webster and Cambridge Dictionaries Online refer to *got* ([MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/got),[CDO](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/got)) and *gotten* ([MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gotten), [COD](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/gotten))  as  **past participles** of *get*.

So to me, your sentence should be

> The letter was **gotten** yesterday.

This is grammatical, but I would prefer *received*. I'm not sure why, but it sounds better.

Also, if we pretend that the word *gotten* does not exist, then I don't believe it is the case that the word *get* does not have a past participle. It does, it just happens to be the same word *got*. It does not have a *different* form. I understand that this might be a technical matter, but I brought it up anyway for illustrative purposes.

The same is true with *read*.

> The book was **read** by the author.

I don't know if this has a name, but here is [a list](http://speakspeak.com/resources/vocabulary-general-english/english-irregular-verbs) that might help you find other words that don't have a *different* past participle form.

Comment: Could you find me examples with reliable sources?

Comment: What are you talking about? Please be specific.

Comment: I have LDOCE, paper edition, I added the information into my question

Comment: I have updated my answer

Comment: Oh, I see what you are saying. I didn't know there existed a "passive form". From what I read, you need a "past participle" to construct the passive voice. I didn't know there was a "passive form". I will try to look into it.